# Match regex from right to left?

Tags: regex

Is there any way of matching a regex from right to left? What Im looking for is a regex that gets

```
MODULE WAS INSERTED              EVENT
LOST SIGNAL ON E1/T1 LINK        OFF
CRC ERROR                        EVENT
CLK IS DIFF FROM MASTER CLK SRC  OF
```

from this input

```
CLI MUX trap received: (022) CL-B  MCL-2ETH             MODULE WAS INSERTED              EVENT   07-05-2010 12:08:40
CLI MUX trap received: (090) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    LOST SIGNAL ON E1/T1 LINK        OFF     04-06-2010 09:58:58
CLI MUX trap received: (094) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    CRC ERROR                        EVENT   04-06-2010 09:58:59
CLI MUX trap received: (009)                            CLK IS DIFF FROM MASTER CLK SRC  OFF     07-05-2010 12:07:32
```

If i could have done the matching from right to left I could have written something like everything to right of (EVENT|OFF) until the second appearance of more than one space [  ]+

The best I managed today is to get everything from (022) to EVENT with the regex

```
CLI MUX trap received: \([0-9]+\)[ ]+(.*[  ]+(EVENT|OFF))
```

But that is not really what I wanted :)

edit: What language its for? Its actually a config string for a filter we have but my guess it is using standard GNU C Regex library.

edit2: I like the answers about cutting by length but Amarghosh was probably more what I was looking for. Do not really know why I did not think about just cutting on length like:

```
^.{56}(.{39}).*$
```

Super thanks for the quick answers...

Comment: What language? Always specify this when asking regex.

Comment: I noticed that the input is fixed-width. You could also simply use a substring instead of a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tokens are guaranteed to be separated by more than one space and words within the string before `EVENT|OFF` are guaranteed to be separated by just one space - only then you can look for single-space-separated words followed by spaces followed by `EVENT` or `OFF`

```
var s = "CLI MUX trap received: (022) CL-B  MCL-2ETH             MODULE WAS INSERTED              EVENT   07-05-2010 12:08:40"
        + "\nCLI MUX trap received: (090) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    LOST SIGNAL ON E1/T1 LINK        OFF     04-06-2010 09:58:58"
        + "\nCLI MUX trap received: (094) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    CRC ERROR                        EVENT   04-06-2010 09:58:59"
        + "\nCLI MUX trap received: (009)                            CLK IS DIFF FROM MASTER CLK SRC  OFF     07-05-2010 12:07:32"

var r = /\([0-9]+\).+?((?:[^ ]+ )* +(?:EVENT|OFF))/g;
var m;
while((m = r.exec(s)) != null)
  console.log(m[1]);
```

Output:

```
MODULE WAS INSERTED              EVENT
LOST SIGNAL ON E1/T1 LINK        OFF
CRC ERROR                        EVENT
CLK IS DIFF FROM MASTER CLK SRC  OFF
```

---

Regex: `/\([0-9]+\).+?((?:[^ ]+ )* +(?:EVENT|OFF))/g`

```
\([0-9]+\)       #digits in parentheses followed by  
.+?              #some characters - minimum required (non-greedy)  
(                #start capturing 
(?:[^ ]+ )*      #non-space characters separated by a space  
` +`             #more spaces (separating string and event/off - 
                 #backticks added for emphasis), followed by
(?:EVENT|OFF)    #EVENT or OFF
)                #stop capturing
```

Answer (score 21):

In .NET you could use the `RightToLeft` [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28VS.85%29.aspx) :

```
Regex RE = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
Match theMatch = RE.Match(Source);
```

Answer (score 4):

With regex, you could simply replace this:

```
^.{56}|.{19}$
```

with the empty string.

But really, you only need to cut out the string from "position 56" to "string-length - 19" with a substring function. That's easier and *much* faster than regex.

Here's an example in JavaScript, other languages work more or less the same:

```
var lines = [
  'CLI MUX trap received: (022) CL-B  MCL-2ETH             MODULE WAS INSERTED              EVENT   07-05-2010 12:08:40',
  'CLI MUX trap received: (090) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    LOST SIGNAL ON E1/T1 LINK        OFF     04-06-2010 09:58:58',
  'CLI MUX trap received: (094) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    CRC ERROR                        EVENT   04-06-2010 09:58:59',
  'CLI MUX trap received: (009)                            CLK IS DIFF FROM MASTER CLK SRC  OFF     07-05-2010 12:07:32'
];
for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
  alert( lines[i].substring(56, lines[i].length-19) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the input file fit nicely into fixed width tabular text like this? Because if it does, then the simplest solution is to just take the right `substring` of each line, from column 56 to column 94.

In Unix, you can use the `cut` command:

```
cut -c56-94 yourfile
```

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Cut (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29)

---

In Java, you can write something like this:

```
String[] lines = {
    "CLI MUX trap received: (022) CL-B  MCL-2ETH             MODULE WAS INSERTED              EVENT   07-05-2010 12:08:40",
    "CLI MUX trap received: (090) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    LOST SIGNAL ON E1/T1 LINK        OFF     04-06-2010 09:58:58",
    "CLI MUX trap received: (094) IO-2  ML-1E1        EX1    CRC ERROR                        EVENT   04-06-2010 09:58:59",
    "CLI MUX trap received: (009)                            CLK IS DIFF FROM MASTER CLK SRC  OFF     07-05-2010 12:07:32",
};
for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line.substring(56, 94));
}
```

This prints:

```
MODULE WAS INSERTED              EVENT
LOST SIGNAL ON E1/T1 LINK        OFF  
CRC ERROR                        EVENT
CLK IS DIFF FROM MASTER CLK SRC  OFF
```

---

#### A regex solution

This is most likely not necessary, but something like this works ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/uswqr)):

```
line.replaceAll(".*  \\b(.+  .+)   \\S+ \\S+", "$1")
```

As you can see, it's not very readable, and you have to know your regex to really understand what's going on.

Essentially you match this to each line:

```
.*  \b(.+  .+)   \S+ \S+
```

And you replace it with whatever group 1 matched. This relies on the usage of two consecutive spaces exclusively for separating the columns in this table.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
.{56}(.*(EVENT|OFF))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do field-oriented processing, rather than a regex?  In awk/sh, this would look like:

`< $datafile awk '{ print $(NF-3), $(NF-2) }' | column`

which seems rather cleaner than specifying a regex.