# Can you match right-to-left in vim like you can in .NET?

Tags: .net, vim

In .NET you [can match from right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989643/18149) instead of left-to-right.  Can this be done in vim?

Comment: An example would help understand the question better. It should be doable with a regex

Comment: From what [I understand](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/04/10/practical-use-cases-for-the-regexoptions-flags) `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` is a performance option. I don't know of any regex option to enable such a behavior in Vim. I also highly doubt there is much call for such a behavior. As @Amit asked, Do you have an example application?

Comment: I figured out how to do what I was attempting to do in Powershell.  I was trying to get filenames off the end of a path in vim, but Powershell did the trick with a Split and doing a [-1] to get the last item in the array.  Regex was probably overkill in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you anchor the regular expression to the end via `$`, the engine probably does this. Vim 7.4 has a different NFA-based engine; you can switch between both with the `'regexpengine'` option (by default, Vim selects the "best" for each pattern), which can improve performance. But there's no explicit option for right-to-left matching, no.