# How to get specific string from the bunch of texts in reverse order using preg_match() in PHP

Tags: php

Currently I am using below code for getting specific string from the texts.

```
preg_match('~background(.*?).png~', $css_content, $output);
```

I use this code for getting specific text from bunch of the text. This code works but it goes serially that is left to right.
 
For example:
Let's say following of texts

> "color:#fff; background:url('assets/imgages/background.png');"

Now I want to get text "  background:url('assets/images/background.png  "

The function preg_match() works like this: 
It first finds the "background" text that I've added in above function then it finds for ".png" text also added in function. This looks like it works left to right. But I want to make it opposite that is right to left.

What I want to do is, function should find ".png" first and then it should be go for "background" text.

Comment: Regexp use to work from left to right. Here you'll find interesting details on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989606/match-regex-from-right-to-left But why do you need regexp operates in opposite direction? What would be the matching you are looking for? Give an example. Maybe it can be done with normal direction, left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use so called **positive look ahead**.

> ~(background...(?=\.png)~

-> finds the background (if .png is after it)

In your situation:

```
preg_match('~background(.*?)(?=\.png)~', $css_content, $output);
```

You can test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/kC2rO2/1