# regex time differs a lot in reverse version of a pattern

Tags: python, regex, performance, text

I want to extract lines with specific patterns in a large python file. I tried to open the file in bathes and extract the lines by regex. As the file is so large the performance is important for me. So, i managed the following patterns:

```
import re
start = time.time()

s = re.findall('1167331\t\d{4,}', file)

middle = time.time()

s2 = re.findall('\d{4,}\t1167331', file)

end = time.time()
print(end - middle, middle - start)
```

The results:

```
87.53701615333557 1.5457119941711426
```

What is the reason of the difference? and how i can solve this?
I think the regex goes from start of pattern to the end so the first pattern will be faster. As the documentation asserts:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.

If it's correct, is there a way to come up with this? Is it possible to force regex to match from right to left? An answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989606/match-regex-from-right-to-left) says that there is in .NET.
A part of my data:

```
file[:200]

'1000061\t11172522\n1000211\t1084791\n1000211\t1087381\n1000211\t1113071\n1000211\t1167331\n1000211\t5997662\n1000211\t7006722\n1000211\t7763732\n1000211\t13075162\n1000211\t13550632\n1000211\t14367563\n1000211\t14373036\n100'
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines of sample data?

Comment: @Nick Reed, i added.

Comment: 2 ideas: 1. start your pattern with a word boundary `\b`, or 2. read your data line by line and test each line with `endswith`.

Comment: Think something is wrong the way it's being done. Even if the first regex didn't match anything it still has to search through every number.before it fails. This disparity shouldn't be 50 to 1, that's not possible. Btw, the first regex doesn't match any in the sample data. For a valid test, each regex should match the exact same thing. And must add iterations to smooth the result.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, i am using regex because for loop line by line is very slow and in my case impossible.

Comment: @x15, I don't know why you say that it does not match any thing. I get this from the first regex: ['1167331\t1000211', '1167331\t1113071'].

Comment: Perhaps, instead of focusing on the regex speed, try to write your code in a lazy evaluation way. (In this way reading the file by lines makes sense).

Comment: You can also use a simple substring search and play with offsets to extract the whole line.

Comment: Talking about the sample data you've provided in the post. No, it doesn't match anything from the first regex https://regex101.com/r/PtBK2x/1. That's beside the point though, there is no way there should be a 50x disparity between the two regex. Either way the first regex has to be cleaned up to match the same as the second. I suggest getting a professional benchmarking app to try different techniques http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b2.jpg where you can load multi-megabyte sample data to test.

Comment: If the need is to use the second regex use @CasimiretHippolyte 's advice there and add a word boundary before the digits `\b\d{4,}\t1167331` this will limit backtracking only to word boundary's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is behaving this way because `\d{4,}` can match a LOT of different combinations, and if the number after `\t` isn't valid, *it has to check them all*. Suppose we have:

`1000211\t875349678\t1000211`

If `\d{4}` comes first, and the number after `\t` isn't `1167331`, it has to check `1000211\t`, `000211\t`, `00211\t`, `0211\t` before it determines that the number past the `\t` isn't valid. Imagine if your numbers were longer - it would have to check even more content before moving to the next one! What's worse, if the number after `\t` is *almost* valid, it'll check all of those characters too, taking even longer to run.

If `1167331` comes first, it only has to check `10` before it fails and moves to the next number.

Check out a debugger step-through of your [slow](https://regex101.com/r/ERCqp6/2/debugger) and [fast](https://regex101.com/r/ERCqp6/1/debugger) regexes - you'll see pretty quick what the difference is.

Comment: Well, we would need a bit more info. Are you trying to capture only `\t` or also `\n`? Do you know your regexes capture two different things? What exactly are you trying to capture?

Comment: Actually, i want to capture each line that contains the number (So no need to \n). First i had a combined regex and the bad performance led me to check the cause.

Comment: Like this? `(^.*1167331.*$)` - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ERCqp6/3)

Comment: This does not match anything. Removing ^ and $ solve the problem but is so slow.

Comment: If your file literally includes the characters `\n` and `\t`, maybe something like `\\n(?:\d+\\t)?1167331(?:\\t\d+)?` [(Demo)](https://regex101.com/r/ERCqp6/4) would be better.

Comment: It is slow, too.